# How can I change the TabLyout Text Color in Material3

Tags: android, android-theme, material-components-android, material3

in Material3 TabLayout Text color is not Changing. TabLayout Background color changes by using surface color but the text color is not changing with ColorOnSurface! also custom TabStyle not working in Material3. here is my Custom TabStyle.

```
<style name="customTabLayout" parent="Widget.Material3.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">2.5dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingStart">6dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingEnd">6dp</item>
    <item name="tabBackground">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Have you tried "tabTextColor"?

Comment: @TheLibrarian yes tabTextColor work fine on Material2 but not working on Material3

Comment: There is also tabTextAppearance that could technically override that.

Comment: not working I think the surfaceColor override the TabLayout background color but I can't figure out the Tablayout Text Color!

Answer (score 0):

The default text colors in the **M3** `TabLayout` are based on (see [all states](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/tree/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/tabs/res/color/m3_tabs_icon_color.xml)):

- **`colorOnSurfaceVariant`**: not selected
- **`colorPrimary`**: selected

You can override them using the **`materialThemeOverlay`** attribute in the style:

```
<style name="Widget.App.TabLayout" parent="Widget.Material3.TabLayout">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.TabLayout</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.TabLayout" parent="">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red500_dark</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurfaceVariant">@color/blu500_dark</item>
</style>
```

and in your layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    style="@style/Widget.App.TabLayout"
```

[image]

You can achieve the same using in your layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.App.TabLayout"
```

In any case, the tab item text color is defined by the `tabTextColor` attribute and you can totally override the default selector using:

```
<style name="Widget.App.TabLayout" parent="Widget.Material3.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabTextColor">@color/selector_teal_700</item>
</style>
```

Use a selector like [this](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/tree/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/tabs/res/color/m3_tabs_icon_color.xml) and in your layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    style="@style/Widget.App.TabLayout"
```

[image]